# Bytes function in python 2.7 takes only one argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

I know `bytes()` in python 3.7  that takes up to 3 arguments,however i am using python 2.7, i am trying count n-grams after cleaning the text, the problem is that `bytes` function but it is giving me the following error.

I have tried to encode it using `encode("utf-8")` but it didn't fix the problem, i also tried to leave it with just the "content" but it crashes as soon as it hits a weird character(i.e Latin symbols or math symbols).

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re,string
def cleanInput(input):
    input=re.sub('\n+'," ",input)
    input=re.sub("\[[0-9]*\]","",input)
    input=re.sub(" +"," ",input)
    input=bytes(input).encode("utf-8")
    input=input.decode("ascii","ignore")
    cleanInput=[]
    input=input.split(" ")
    for item in input:
        item.strip(string.punctuation)
        if len(item)>1 or item.lower()=='i' or item.lower()=="a":
            cleanInput.append(item)
    return cleanInput
```

I expect to replace the command `bytes(content,"utf-8")` with a line that does the same, here is the error i am getting 
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 90: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: In Python 2.7, `bytes` is the same as `str`. Consider using [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#bytearray) instead. What type of object do you pass to your `cleanInput` function?

Comment: large text @myrmica

Comment: What is 'large text'?  unicode? ascii, something else?

Comment: `input`...bad name...Python has an `input` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You encode Unicode, and decode bytes.  Python 2 will implicitly convert to the right type using the `ascii` codec if you use the wrong one, which produces the error you see.  Note that Python 3 won't do that, so it is easier to catch mistakes.

If `input` is type `unicode`, then just use `input.encode('utf8').decode('ascii','ignore')` to remove all Unicode code points > U+00FF.

If `input` is type `str`, then just use `input.decode('ascii','ignore')`.

P.S. Don't use the names of Python built-in functions as variable names.  `input()` is a built-in.